# Parametric Equations for a Hypercone

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric

The n-dimensional cone, with vertex at the origin, central angle, $\alpha$ and central axis in the direction of the unit vector $\xi$ is defined to be all those points, $x\in {R^n}$ whose dot product with $\xi$ is |$x$|$cos(\alpha)$.  How would I find parametric equations for this surface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest answer is if $\xi$ is along one of the axes, say the first.  Then the cone can be parameterized as  $(t\cos(\alpha ),t\sin(\alpha){\bf\hat{x}})$, where ${\bf\hat{x}}$ is a unit vector in $\mathbb{R^{n-1}}$.  In coordinates, this is $(t\cos(\alpha ),t\sin(\alpha )\cos(\phi_1),t\sin(\alpha )\sin(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2),t\sin(\alpha )\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)\cos(\phi_3),\ldots)$ where you have n-1 angular terms and the last has no cosine.  If n>3, $\phi_1$ runs from 0 to $\pi$ while the others run from 0 to $2\pi$.  Then you can apply a rotation matrix to take $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ to $\xi$.

Comment: Shouldn't $\phi_1$ run from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the rest run from $0$ to $\pi$, instead of the other way around?

Comment: In the last sentence of your answer, you suggest to apply a rotation to the coordinate system - how would this change the angles that define the cone? It seems to me that after a general rotation by matrix $\mathbf{R}$, the angles will become interdependent with, say, $\phi_1$ becoming a function of $\phi_2, \phi_3$ etc. What is the methodology for working out these inter-dependencies and new ranges of angels that define the cone after rotation? Thank you.

Comment: PS. I have tried taking projections of rotated unit basis vectors and taking dot products of these projection with each other and the original basis vectors, but it gets confusing and not clear how to deduce new relationships and ranges.  Thank you.